# Cannot create NVARCHAR column in MariaDb/Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDb server (Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.7-MariaDB).
When I execute

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL,
   `name` NVARCHAR(64) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Describe output:

```
MariaDB [db]> describe my_table;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why there is no error, and "name" column datatype is varchar (not nvarchar)?

db schema details:

```
Default collation: utf8_general_ci
Default characterset: utf8
```

Comment: Maybe this part of the documentation helps: *NATIONAL VARCHAR is the standard SQL way to define that a VARCHAR column should use some predefined character set. MariaDB uses utf8 as this predefined character set, as does MySQL 4.1 and up*

Comment: @Jens - you literally beat me to it by 60 seconds.  This is, IMHO, the "correct answer".

Comment: @Jens - The default continued to be `latin1` for many versions.  Finally, in 8.0, the default became `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NVARCHAR` is a synonym for `VARCHAR` in MySQL/MariaDB.  But you need to add the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` to be sure that you get full UTF-8 support.

What you show as the default for that database is only the subset, called 'utf8'.  It will not handle Emoji or some of Chinese.